# How to uninstall partially installed module with Pip

Tags: pip, uninstallation, cancellation

I recently decided to try to install tesseract onto my computer and ran `pip3 install tesseract-ocr`.

It then started to download `cython` which alerted me to the fact that `tesseract-ocr` was not what I wanted, so I hit CTRL-C to cancel the command.

However, it appears that there is still a Cython folder inside my directories; pip did not clean up after the cancel. Also, I can't use `pip uninstall cython` because it just tells me it hasn't been installed yet.

What can I do to get a clean removal of Cython?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FWIW, the package name you gave doesn't appear to be on the global pypi index, so perhaps you left some steps out?

```
pip3 install opencv-tesseract
Collecting opencv-tesseract
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement opencv-tesseract 
  (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for opencv-tesseract
```

In this type of situation, I think the answer becomes:

1. In the future, let it finish installing, then uninstall it once complete, so that it can clean itself up properly.
2. Don't panic if pip is installing dependencies of the thing you're installing. When I `pip3 install tesseract-ocr` as in the edited question, I see:

   ```
   Collecting tesseract-ocr
     Downloading tesseract-ocr-0.0.1.tar.gz
   Collecting cython (from tesseract-ocr)
   ...
   ```

   Which is totally normal and just indicates you are installing a dependency of your dependency, in this case `cython`, so no need to cancel it.
3. Install dependencies to disposable `virtualenv`s so that you don't pollute your global packages and file system: https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/stable/
4. You will probably just have to delete the leftover `cython` directories.

Comment: Thanks for noticing the package name: edited to have the correct package name: tesseract-ocr

Comment: @ProQ Gotcha :)  I've edited my answer to confirm `cython` is an expected dependency of the package you were installing. You might be able to finish the original installation over top the incomplete one in order to run `pip3 uninstall tesseract-ocr` afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

While you can delete the files manually (usually residing in the folder `site-packages`, it is better to completely reinstall the package, and then use `pip uninstall <package>` in order to completely uninstall it.

Answer (score 0):

I also had this problem when I lost power to my Pi part way through installing linux-remote.

I deleted the `.whl` file to resolve the problem, which was located here in my case:

```
/root/.cache/pip/wheels/a0/75/....../linux-remote-3.4-cp37-none-any.whl
```